# C++ boost callback returning data

Tags: c++, boost, callback

I am struggling with the syntax to get data back from a callback (not sending parameters to the callback). I can get the callback to trigger without data, but would appreciate some guidance on what I am missing. As listed it works without returning data, swap out the neighbouring commented out lines for my attempt as returning data (so the mistake is likely in there).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef boost::function<void()> callback;       
//typedef boost::function<void(std::string)> callback;    // With return argument

class B
{
public:
    //typedef boost::shared_ptr<const printer> SharedConst;

    B(boost::asio::io_service& io, std::string name_, int target_, callback call_)
    : timer_(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1)),
      count(1), target(target_), name(name_), call(call_)
    {
        timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&B::print, this));
    }
    
    ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "Final count is " << count << "\n";
    }
 
    void print()
    {
        if (count < target)
        {
            std::cout << name << " : " << count << "\n";
            ++count;

            timer_.expires_at(timer_.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
            timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&B::print, this));
        } 
        else {
            call();
            //call(name);
        }
    }

private:
    callback call;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
    int count;
    int target;
    std::string name;
};

class A {
private:
    std::map<std::string, B*> jobs;
    boost::asio::io_service io;

public:
    void acceptResult()
    //void acceptResult(std::string jobID_)
    {
        std::cout << "acceptResult" << std::endl; 
        //std::cout << "acceptResult from job : " << jobID_<< std::endl; 
        //free(jobs.at(jobID_));   
        //auto it = jobs.find(jobID_);
        //jobs.erase(it);
    }

    void newJob(std::string jobID_, unsigned int target)
    {
        B *b = new B(io, jobID_, target, boost::bind(&A::acceptResult, this));
        jobs.insert({jobID_, b});
    }

    void run()
    {
        io.run();
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.newJob("j1", 5);
    a.newJob("j2", 3);

    a.run();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output (without returning a value):**

```
j1 : 1
j2 : 1
j1 : 2
j2 : 2
j1 : 3
acceptResult
j1 : 4
acceptResult
```

Thanks in advance, Paul.

Comment: What C++ version are you using? If you are using C++11 or newer, you can simplify this by using lambdas etc.

Comment: I have cmake set to 20, so happy to try anything new =). The last lambda exmple I saw looked like a cat fell face first into the brackets section of the keyboard...Could you provide an example?

Comment: Sure. I wasn't able to get boost's `async_wait` to accept the lambdas but at least the one that mattered (`boost::bind(&A::acceptResult, this)`) that used a deprecated feature of implicit placeholders (`_1`) (or something to that effect).  I included `<boost/bind/bind.hpp>` for the rest of the `bind`s after replacing it with a lambda. I need to go to bed so I can't give you a full answer of the things I did, but [here's the result](https://godbolt.org/z/nWK7s8dzx)

Comment: ... or if you really want to autostart the jobs, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/PKs41T4ec) may be an alternative.

Comment: Thanks Ted! I hadn't gotten around to looking for that bind warning and you got that too =). I appreciate you cleaning up my example. I learnt a few things =).

Comment: You're welcome! I may write a proper answer after work if noone else has done so by then :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's clean up some problems:

- initialization order (`callback` after `name`)
- memory leaks (`jobs` should manage the job lifetimes):
- destruction order (`io` should go AFTER `jobs`)

I probably fixed more, but I forget: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8004188c07c25ad7):

```
j1 : 1
j2 : 1
j1 : 2
j2 : 2
j1 : 3
acceptResult
j1 : 4
acceptResult
Final count is 3
Final count is 5
```

### The Problem

Uncommenting the "question" lines I notice you forgot to `bind` a placeholder for the `name` argument:

```
boost::bind(&A::acceptResult, this, boost::placeholders::_1)
```

That's all! Due to my choice for `unique_ptr` there's no need for the complicated (and not exception-safe) dance. Oh, not to mention that `free` is NOT correct with `new`/`delete`!

```
void acceptResult(std::string jobID_) {
    std::cout << "acceptResult from job : " << jobID_<< std::endl;
    jobs.erase(jobID_);
}
```

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baaa9082a96a3717)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using callback = std::function<void(std::string)>; // With return argument

class B {
  public:
    B(boost::asio::io_service& io, std::string name_, int target_, callback call_)
        : timer_(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1))
        , count(1)
        , target(target_)
        , name(name_)
        , call(call_) {
        timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&B::print, this));
    }

    ~B() { std::cout << "Final count is " << count << "\n"; }

    void print() {
        if (count < target) {
            std::cout << name << " : " << count << "\n";
            ++count;

            timer_.expires_at(timer_.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
            timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&B::print, this));
        } else {
             call(name);
        }
    }

  private:
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
    int                         count;
    int                         target;
    std::string                 name;
    callback                    call;
};

class A {
  private:
    boost::asio::io_service                   io; // ORDER! destruct last
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<B>> jobs;

  public:
    void acceptResult(std::string jobID_) {
        std::cout << "acceptResult from job : " << jobID_<< std::endl;
        jobs.erase(jobID_);
    }

    void newJob(std::string jobID_, unsigned int target) {
        jobs.emplace(jobID_,
                     std::make_unique<B>(io, jobID_, target,
                                         boost::bind(&A::acceptResult, this, boost::placeholders::_1)));
    }

    void run() { io.run(); }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.newJob("j1", 5);
    a.newJob("j2", 3);

    a.run();
}
```

Prints

```
j1 : 1
j2 : 1
j1 : 2
j2 : 2
j1 : 3
acceptResult from job : j2
Final count is 3
j1 : 4
acceptResult from job : j1
Final count is 5
```

Comment: Thanks sehe, both for fixing it in 'the original' non-lambda way as that was still bugging me as to why it was wrong and for fixing my other errors.

Comment: @Paul That's the _"deprecated feature of implicit placeholders (`_1`)"_ I mentioned. I should have just added it to show where it goes but opted for a (imho) simpler lambda. I also used `unique_ptr`s as a test but got a race condition. Strange. I just added it to my code now and of course it works like a charm :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Can you point me to documentation/examples of such "implicit placeholders"? To the best of my knowledge no such feature ever existed in Boost Bind. It's possible that there's confusion with Boost Lambda/Phoenix placeholders, or even with the default declaration of global namespace placeholders, which, indeed, were recently deprecated (but were never implicit, just polluting the global namespace).

Comment: @sehe I didn't get it from the documentation but from when compiling, but I didn't remember the exact message correctly. It was: _"The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> ..."_ - So, not the same thing no...

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah, that's the deprecation I referred to, then. It has nothing to do with placeholders being "implicit" in any functional way, so it didn't contribute to the problem/solution (except for generating deprecation warnings on recent boost versions). I just change the includes for good measure, always.

Comment: @sehe You are correct. I remembered it incorrectly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Cheers! Thanks for spending time on here and sharing your expertise. Much appreciated

Comment: @sehe English is not my first language, but that's meant to be ironic, isn't it? If so: You're welcome :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo no no no, completely honest. I know firsthand that contributing on this site can be time-consuming and relatively thank-less. And I know I've seen some deeply insightful stuff from you so I'm very happy to be able to ask you things, and to see you help people on this site. (English isn't my first language either, but honestly I think it's more about people never expressing thanks, or not nearly enough that has people worried when it happens!)

Comment: @sehe Oh, in that case, thank you very much and thanks for your many contributions too! Yes, it's easy to misunderstand. I thought that since I messed up a bit here, a little "nudge" would be warranted and I wasn't taking offence :-)